# Newbie - what do I need to do with httpd.conf to make CakePHP work correctly?

Tags: cakephp, httpd.conf

(Not sure if this belongs here or on webmasters; please move if necessary.)

I'm a total newbie to Cake and not much better with apache; I've done
a lot of PHP but always with a server that's already been set up by
someone else. So I'm going through the [basic blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/326/The-Cake-Blog-Tutorial), and it
says:

> A Note On mod_rewrite
>   Occasionally a new user will run in to mod_rewrite issues, so I'll
>   mention them marginally here. If the Cake welcome page looks a little
>   funny (no images or css styles), it probably means mod_rewrite isn't
>   functioning on your system. Here are some tips to help get you up and
>   running:
>
> Make sure that an .htaccess override is allowed: in your httpd.conf,
>   you should have a section that defines a section for each Directory on
>   your server. Make sure the AllowOverride is set to All for the correct
>   Directory.
>
> Make sure you are editing the system httpd.conf rather than a user- or
>   site-specific httpd.conf.
>
> For some reason or another, you might have obtained a copy of CakePHP
>   without the needed .htaccess files. This sometimes happens because
>   some operating systems treat files that start with '.' as hidden, and
>   don't copy them. Make sure your copy of CakePHP is from the downloads
>   section of the site or our SVN repository.
>
> Make sure you are loading up mod_rewrite correctly! You should see
>   something like LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/httpd/mod_rewrite.so
>   and AddModule mod_rewrite.c in your httpd.conf."

I'm using XAMPP on linux. I've found my httpd.conf file in opt/lampp/
etc, but am not sure what I need to do with it. I've searched for
"rewrite", and there's only one line:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

There's nothing about AddModule mod_rewrite.c.

Do I just create a Directory section for the directory I've installed
Cake in and set AlllowOverride to All? (I created a separate
subdirectory of my wwwroot and installed in there, since I also have
installs of Joomla and CodeIgniter.) Is there anything else I need to
do? My download of Cake did come with two htaccess-type files
(._.htaccess and .htaccess) - do I need to do anything with them?

Thanks for any help you can provide to this non-server-admin.

EDIT TO ADD virtual host sample:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. You should have mod_rewrite enabled, check using `<?php phpinfo();`

Step 2. Check AllowOverride

```
// I believe you already did that. 
// Make sure you are doing it for the correct webroot!
<Directory />
   AlllowOverride to All
</Directory>
```

Step 3. Check your default `.htaccess` files are there in directories `/mypro`, `/mypro/app`, `/mypro/app/webroot`.

Step 4. `.htaccess` may need path fixes depending upon your cake project installation.

```
 e.g. project url http://localhost/mypro/app/webroot/
 /mypro/app/webroot/.htacess
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ mypro/app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) mypro/app/webroot/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

## EDIT

If you are trying to setup it as local domains, Setup local domains (on windows) with WAMP configured
**Note: this may be tweaked a little for different kind of installations**
Find your hosts file (mine is located at C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
Insert this to bottom

```
# save and close this file named hosts
127.0.0.1       mypro.localhost
```

To test hostname open command prompt and run ping mypro.localhost `# If ping is good then move on`

```
Now open your apache config file 
httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf (my files are located at)

C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\httpd.conf
# uncomment line below
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
# Insert virtual host entries like this, trim dummy entries (if any)

# Changing DocumentRoot
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mypro/app/webroot"
    ServerName mypro.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close files

Create directory C:/wamp/www/mypro (if you haven’t created before)

Comment: Thanks for all the info, but as I said in the OP, I'm using XAMPP on Linux, so all the windows-specific info doesn't really help. Also, in your step 3, what does /mypro refer to? I don't have any directories called mypro.

Comment: `mypro` is abbrivation for `my project` this is whatever the name of your project.

Comment: for linux installation replace all path to you current installation.  e.g. "C:/wamp/www/mypro" might get replaced with "/var/www/vhosts/mypro"

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a var/www folder either; XAMPP isn't set up that way. The actual file path (from the machine root) is /opt/lampp/htdocs/myNewWebApp. So should the filepath be /opt/lampp/htdocs/myNewWebapp?

Comment: Yes, but i usually set my webroot as DocumentRoot which is your `/opt/lampp/htdocs/myNewWebap/app/webroot`

Comment: OK, as I stated, I know next to nothing about server config. Is webroot global (serverwide) or is it local to each application? I have multiple applications running on this server (/opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla, /opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter, /opt/lampp/htdocs/CakePHP). I don't want to set a global webroot, unless it's /opt/lampp/htdocs/. I want to be able to acecss URLs like http://localhost/joomla/index.php, http://localhost/CakePHP/index.php, etc.

Comment: You can set separate DocumentRoot for your application, refer to "Changing DocumentRoot" in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ModRewrite enables Apache to manipulate request URLs before it handles the request. For example, if you wanted to store your images in `/website_images` but you wanted to reference them in your HTML as `/img/donkey.jpg` you could use ModRewrite to change all requests from `/img/*` to `/website_images/*`. The way that it handles this is through Regular Expressions, which have entire books written about them.

As far as Apache goes, there are lots of configuration "directives" (aka options or settings). The most crucial to learn about when you're running your own server are going to be the VirtualHost ones. They allow Apache to handle requests to your server's IP address and route them to the correct website based on the hostname (the domain, essentially). You should place any website-specific directives within that website's VirtualHost configuration, including your ModRewrite rules. Note: you can also load additional directives from a .htaccess file in the website's directory, but this is suboptimal (and requires AllowOverride to be set. If you have access to httpd.conf and the related VirtualHost directives, you should use them instead.

It looks like Apache is already configured to load the ModRewrite module, so you don't need to change that. In the VirtualHost directives for your new CakePHP website, you can use the following directives under the `<Directory /path/to/your/website>` to setup ModRewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It looks big and scary, but what that does is tells Apache to direct all requests that it can't handle (because the resources don't exist) to index.php. When that happens, CakePHP takes over and routes the request to the appropriate controller and action.

I'm not familiar with how XAMPP is configured, so I can't tell you where those VirtualHost definitions are going to be. Perhaps someone else can chime in here…

Comment: Thanks for the info, Corey! In my main httpd.conf file, there's a line that says: # Virtual hosts
#Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf - I've added a sample of what's in that file to the OP above; do I just copy the entire block and replace *:80 with my app path?

Comment: That would lead me to believe that Apache is configured to run without VirtualHosts. You can do this, but it means that you can only run one website at a time. If you're fine with that, you can go ahead and look for any existing `<Directory /path/here>` lines that point to your application and add the Rewrite code inside of them. If you want to use VirtualHosts, then you sound like you're on the right track; uncommenting the include line, and cracking open the httpd-vhosts.conf file to add the rewrite directives.

Comment: And then add your IfModule code block inside the VirtualHost block?

Comment: Yes. Check out the Apache documentation for some example VirtualHost definitions so you know what to expect and how it should look at the very least. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Uncomment the include line, and inside the VirtualHost block you should have a `<Directory /path/here>` block that has the path to your application. You can put the IfModule block inside that. The `*:80` allows/informs Apache to bind to any IP address on port 80, which is fine; you don't need to change it any.

Comment: Just saw you added the VirtualHost to your question. You should just replace it with the following, updated to match your website: `<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

<Directory /www/example1>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>`