# Where is the "system" httpd.conf file?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, wamp

Why does there have to be errors -_-'

Where can I find "system httpd.conf". I researched and tried to find what httpd.conf file they were talking about in this tutorial to fix my CakePHP startup issue. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/in8fd.png ) the issue being **"URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server."**

The file is not in wamp (which also contains cakePHP )  https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5or4.png

Where is it? I was suppose to make this "cashier webtool" for this interview because they wanted to see if I could pick up cake fast enough. I never got to actually work with Cake Because of all these hang ups. i even tried to host cake on my online server. That failed too
http://y.k8r.us
This is a mess. :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you *have* found it in "\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf".
I'm sure there's more info in the readme files, but the "system" httpd.conf seems like the default settings, which can be overridden in specific directories by placing within them a new httpd.conf which applies to that directory.

I'm no expert on this topic, but it seems like you've taken the words too literally.

Comment: as a side note, I've never set up a wamp server, but I've set up plenty of lamp servers using various types of sql/php server combinations.

Comment: The thing is . I checked that file. http://pastebin.com/vunFmrFz and I did a search for "libexec/apache2" and found nothing. So it can't be that file.

Comment: [**apache documentation about config files**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html) You just need to find your apache folder, it should be in there. Was there a settings file with the WAMP compiler? It probably contains a setting telling where apache is set up and where it's config files are.

Comment: I didn't touch anything in WAMP ever. I downloaded it strictly for cake. I've never used WAMP before.
Same thing with CakePHP. I changed no files.

No code is missing to my knowledge

Comment: check line 118 of the posted file:

Comment: #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so -- as you can see, it's commented out.

Comment: the reason you can't find libexec is because that's a reference to a build in which they placed modules in a libexec folder... probably a linux-based install

Comment: I'm about to try the uncomment now.
alright. i changed that line, exited out of wamp, re-opened it, restarted all services, started all services and then went "online" with wamp. tested the page. 
Still the same error.
BTW, thank you for the help.
Not working yet though :/

Comment: I have now tried it on my Mac. I'm receiving the same error. I'm in MAMP this time. The parallel httpd.conf file looks like this http://pastebin.com/2yx6biCe

Comment: I'm all out of suggestions... sorry. This [stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661127/newbie-what-do-i-need-to-do-with-httpd-conf-to-make-cakephp-work-correctly) may have what you need. I've looked here for reference a couple times, and they seem to be mentioning the blog you're using. Furthermore, one of the answer posters describes steps to take in WAMP, so hopefully that will be helpful.